Can I replicate the behaviour of remote_syslog2 using syslog.conf and asl.conf?
I need to share the syslog over udp to a remote server. I have configured syslog.conf to share the logs with . @remote_server:ip, but not all logs are getting transferred to the server, logs on user authentication failure seems to be missing. I used log stream to write the logs to /var/log/test.log file. This file is however not being picked up by the syslog daemon for forwarding. Is there an option by which I can avoid the usage of remote_syslog2 and any other third party application. Can I just configure asl.conf to replace the use of log stream command
